Can you check if an expression is strictly quadratic in a variable in sympy?
I have some sympy expressions which are functions some variables. Is it possible to check the following in sympy:

Where my expression is strictly quadratic in terms of a variable. For example this expression is strictly quadratic in $\dot{x}$.



Whether the expression is strictly linear in a variable. For example this expression is not strictly linear in $y$ as it has a quadratic term.



Whether it has an explicit dependence on t but not functionally dependent though x(t) or y(t) for example this has a explicit time dependence


but something like this does not:

EDIT:
Here's the code for the last expression to make life easier:
import sympy as sp

expr = sp.sympify("Add(Mul(Integer(-1), Rational(1, 2), Symbol('k'), Pow(Symbol('x_p0'), Integer(2))), Mul(Symbol('k'), Symbol('x_p0'), Function('y')(Symbol('t'))), Mul(Integer(-1), Rational(1, 2), Symbol('k'), Pow(Function('y')(Symbol('t')), Integer(2))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Symbol('m'), Pow(Symbol('v0'), Integer(2))), Mul(Integer(-1), Symbol('m'), Symbol('v0'), Derivative(Function('y')(Symbol('t')), Tuple(Symbol('t'), Integer(1)))), Mul(Rational(1, 2), Symbol('m'), Pow(Derivative(Function('y')(Symbol('t')), Tuple(Symbol('t'), Integer(1))), Integer(2))))")
print(expr)


My solution transforms a SymPy expression into a polynomial of some variable and it checks whether its only polynomial coefficient is with the desired degree
Here the test function:
import sympy as sp

def test_strict_degree(expr, var, degree):
    # test whether an expression has a strict
    # degree in some variable

    # transform the expression into a polynomial
    # of var and check whether its only coefficient
    # is with the desired degree
    poly_coeff = sp.Poly(expr, var).all_coeffs()

    # We revert the coefficient list so that list 
    # indices correspond to degree of polynomial
    poly_coeff = poly_coeff[::-1]

    # all non-zero coefficicients of the polynomial
    ind = [i for i, e in enumerate(poly_coeff) if e != 0]

    if (len(ind) == 1) and degree == ind[0]:
        return True

    return False

The application to the first two expressions yields
k, y, m, t = sp.symbols('k, y, m, t')
x = sp.symbols('x', cls=sp.Function)
x = x(t)

df = sp.diff(x, t)

expr1 = sp.Rational(1, 2) * m * df**2
expr2 = k * (-x + y)**2

test_strict_degree(expr1, df, 2)
# True
test_strict_degree(expr2, y, 2)
# False

